# MKMapView- How to get & display the annotation pins for Near by me addresses/locations from the list of existing address

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I was very new to map kit `MKMapView` application,

I **have a list of 1000 *`addresses`* of members in an organization.**

I *`have get the coordinates`* (lat, long)  all these members *`according to their addresses,`*

using `- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)addres`s method

[by Referring this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595953/how-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-from-address-in-iphone)

And display annotations of all the 1000 members in map view
[By referring this link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/)

But now my requirement is to display only **Near by me Current location memebers locations** only ***`in 2 ways`***,

1. ***Top 20 members nearer by me***
2. ***List of all members surrounded by 50KM around me***

How to implement these two scenarios,

Comment: In which form or scenarios you are saving data of 1000 list address. Using Sqlite or core data OR just server side you are maintaining here in object model ?

Comment: @ArpitKumar using SQlite i have stored addresses

Comment: Ok, that's great. Now you can use @Nazik answer on your iphone programming side. Are you satisfied or searching for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the distance between each member and your current location by

```
CLLocation *memberlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:memberlat longitude:memberlong];

CLLocation *yourcurrentlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentlocationlat longitude:currentlocationlong];

CLLocationDistance distance = [memberlocation distanceFromLocation:yourcurrentlocation];
```

and then using them you can find the nearest members, and using your own logic you have code for your required solution.

If you think comparing 1000 address with self location will took time , then send the self location lat-long to server webservice where you have all the members lat-long , there in the webservice you have to use this following query to find the nearest 20 members.

```
SELECT top (20) id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(13.0610) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(80.2404) ) + sin( radians(13.0610) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers  ORDER BY distance;
```

Here instead of 13.0610 you have to pass your self location latitude, and 80.2404 is longitude

Comment: As explained in question you don't think so it will decrease performance for comparing 1000 addresses by self location.

Comment: @ArpitKumar, is there anyother way to find the distance without comparing the address with the self location?

Comment: @ Nazik,currently NO, i don't have any other way. But i am trying to find out a better way.

Comment: @ Nazik, That's what i am expecting. Great thought , by server side query we can easily solve it. +1 for it